# Unable to view Event Hub Generated Data in Databricks Error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks, azure-eventhub

I have generated dummy Yellow Taxi Data in EventHubs using the Generate Data(Preview)

[image]

[image]

When I attempt to view or (display) the stream data in Databricks using the code below, I get the error:

```
ERROR: Some streams terminated before this command could finish!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit
```

The code used to read the stream is:

```
connectionString = 'Endpoint=sb://carlsspace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=myaccesspolicy;SharedAccessKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXwRM+AEhJ3XsFc=;EntityPath=carlshub'
ehConf = {
  'eventhubs.connectionString' : connectionString
}

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
df = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(df)
```

I should I'm trying to read the stream on Databricks Community Edition

Update:

I changed the code as follows:

```
connectionString = 'Endpoint=sb://carlsspace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=myaccesspolicy;SharedAccessKey=lfZTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXVaNv9wRM+AEhJ3XsFc=;EntityPath=carlshub'

ehConf = {}

# For versions before 2.3.15, set the connection string without encryption
# ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = connectionString

# For 2.3.15 version and above, the configuration dictionary requires that connection string be encrypted.
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)

df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
df = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(df)
```

But I'm now getting the following message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
ERROR: Some streams terminated before this command could finish!
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Input byte array has wrong 4-byte ending unit
```

Regarding the **ERROR** you are facing you need to encrypt the connection string in the configuration dictionary

```
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
```

You need Install the **MAVEN** library `com.microsoft.azure:azure-eventhubs-spark_2.12:2.3.22` on your cluster.

[image]

make sure you have active Event messages in your EventHub
[image]

And you can try the below:

```
namespaceName = "dilieepevnt"
EVENTHUB_NAME = "dileepeventhubnamespc" 
SharedAccessKeyName = "RootManageSharedAccessKey"
SharedAccessKey = "SimgL2vbFb6uMSdDpeSPHzvIf0sZcP3FR+AEhGa8JN0="
connectionString = f"Endpoint=sb://{namespaceName}.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName={SharedAccessKeyName};SharedAccessKey={SharedAccessKey};EntityPath={EVENTHUB_NAME}"
ehConf = {}
ehConf['eventhubs.connectionString'] = sc._jvm.org.apache.spark.eventhubs.EventHubsUtils.encrypt(connectionString)
df = spark \
  .readStream \
  .format("eventhubs") \
  .options(**ehConf) \
  .load()
readInStreamBody = df.withColumn("body", df["body"].cast("string"))
display(readInStreamBody)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @DileenprajnarayanThumula, thanks for getting in touch. You suggested that I encrypt the connection, however if you take a look at my question you will find that I actually did encrypt the connection string

Comment: @Patterson I understand you did encrypt the connection.
my advise is to check if you have installed the correct version of libabry, refersh your events and check if you can find stream is giving you the results. because I even had the same error after I did the refresh I am able to see the stream giving results.

Comment: As an example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-python-get-started-send?tabs=connection-string%2Croles-azure-portal
I have used the send.py file to genrate the events